# Swift 3 lazy caching with enums

Tags: swift, caching, enums, lazy-evaluation

I am making a game in Swift 3, and I was wondering what would be best practice to lazy cache an SKTexture inside an enum (or struct). What I want is to create an SKTexture **only once**, and **only when it is required**. I could create a Singleton, with a (Dictionary / Set / Cache / ...) var and only append a new SKTexture to this var, if a key doesn't already exists or return the value if it does exists, but I have the feeling this should be possible with an enum as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the case of a `struct`, you could simply use a `lazy` property of your `SKTexture`:

```
struct Foo {
    lazy var myTexture: SKTexture = { 
        /* some logic to construct texture only
           ever (at most) once _per Foo instance_ */ 
        return someInitializedSKTextureInstance 
    }()
    /* or, as an immutable
    lazy var myTexture: SKTexture = ... */       
}
```

For an *instance* of `Foo`, `theFooInstance.myTexture` will be instantiated at most once, but the once-only executed closure above.

Enumerations, however, cannot use stored properties, which means you cannot use the approach above. You could, however, use a `static` property in an `enum`: these are lazy by default, and will be instantiated only (at most) once at the first call to them. The difference here is naturally (due to `static`) that this once-only insantiation will hold globally for the `enum` _type), and not for instances of the `enum`.

```
enum Foo {
    case bar, baz
    static var texture: SKTexture = { 
        /* logic to construct some texture ... */
        return someInitializedSKTextureInstance 
    }()
}
```

Naturally the static approach could be used also for the `struct` case.

Comment: OK, this looks promising. If I understand correctly, the first example (struct Foo) will create the same texture when new instances are created, and I want to avoid that. In the second example, will /* logic to construct some texture ... */ run only once, when 'texture' is being referenced a few times?

Comment: @APvG exactly, if you use a static property (you may even change this to an immutable if you wish, `static let texture: SKTexture = ...`: using static properties allow lazy immutables, which is not possible for instance properties) it will only be instantiated _at most once_. The only thing to bear in mind using statics is possible race conditions in multithreaded applications, but since you only want to read the property here, I don't see this being an issue.

Comment: Yes, I will only read the property, so it probably should be a private static var, with a getter?

Comment: I'm usually careful when choosing to/not to use getters over direct access to properties. Why? Many types in Swift are value types, and using getters might retrieve copies of them without adding any actual encapsulation value (read up on any discussion of [getters and setters are evil](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html) for details). In this specific example, however, it could be of value having a getter: `SKTexture` is class type, and you might want to limit access to the static `texture` var only to instances of the class/struct that owns it (`Foo` above).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I would say that giving back copies, is encapsulation, because you cannot alter the value of an instance directly (if it normally contains a reference to the prop inside the instance). You can alter the  copy, and trying to set it back with the setter, but it is the setters responsibility to reject or approve the changes. It is way better then setting a property directly. But I guess I should read the discussion more closely. I am glad you approve the use of the getter I was talking about :)